# Vue doesnt update component on dynamic variable condition change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working with Vuejs. I want to render components based on value of variable val.
My component looks like this

```
<template v-if="this.$val===1">
    <component1 />
 </template>
<template v-if="this.$val===2">
    <component2 />
</template>
```

I have defined a global variable val using Vue.prototype and I am updating it using onclick function,where I am changing value of val to 2 but after clicking it doesnt show component2 instead of component 1.
Define val globally in main.js using following line of code

```
Vue.prototype.$val = 1;
```

Can someone please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**td,dr;** `Vue.prototype`is not reactive.

---

I'm going to enumerate issues as I observe them, hoping you'll find them useful.

1. You're not specifying which version of Vue you're using. Since you're using `Vue.prototype`, I'm going to guess you're using Vue 2.
2. Never use `this` in a `<template>`.
   Inside templates, `this` is implicit (sometimes formulated: *"inside templates `this` doesn't exist"*). What would be `this.stuff` in controller, is `stuff` in the template.
3. You can't conditionally swap the top level `<template>` of a Vue component. You need to take the conditional either one level up or one level down:

- one level up would be: you create separate components, one for each template; declare them and have the `v-if` in their parent component, rendering one, or the other
- one level down would be: you move the `v-if` inside the top level `<template>` tag of the component. Example:

```html
<template><!-- top level can't have `v-if` -->
  <div v-if="val === 1">
    val is 1
    <input v-model="val">
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    val is not 1
    <input v-model="val">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ val: 1 })
}
</script>
```

4. Note `<template>` tags don't render an actual tag. They're just virtual containers which help you logically organise/group their contents, but what gets rendered is only their contents.<sup>***1***</sup> So I could have written the above as:

```html
<template><!-- top level can't have v-if -->
  <template v-if="val === 1">
    <div>
      val is 1
      <input v-model="val"> 
    </div>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <template>
      <template>
        <div>
          val is not 1
          <input v-model="val">
        </div>
      </template>
    </template>
  </template>
</template>
```

And get the exact same DOM output.
For obvious reasons, `<template>` tags become useful when you're working with HTML structures needing to meet particular parent/child constraints (e.g: ul + li, tr + td, tbody + tr, etc...).
They're also useful when combining `v-if` with `v-for`, since you can't place both on a single element (Vue needs to know which structural directive has priority, since applying them in different order could produce different results).

---

Working example with what you're trying to achieve:

```js
Vue.prototype.$state = Vue.observable({ foo: true })

Vue.component('component_1', {
  template: `
<div>
  This is <code>component_1</code>.
  <pre v-text="$state"/>
  <button @click="$state.foo = false">Switch</button>
</div>
`})
Vue.component('component_2', {
  template: `
<div>
  This is <code>component_2</code>.
  <pre v-text="$state"/>
  <button @click="$state.foo = true">Switch back</button>
</div>
`})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <component_1 v-if="$state.foo"></component_1>
   <component_2 v-else></component_2>
 </div>
```

Notes:

- `<div id="app">...</div>` acts as `<template>` for the app instance (which is, also, a Vue component)
- Technically, I could have written that template as:

```html
<div id="app">
  <template v-if="$state.foo">
    <component_1 />
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <component_2 />
  </template>
</div>
```

, which is pretty close to what you were trying. But it would be slightly more verbose than what I used, without any benefit.

- I'm using a [Vue.observable()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable)<sup>***2***</sup> for `$state` because you can't re-assign a Vue global. I mean, you can, but the change will only affect Vue instances created after the change, not the ones already created (including current one). In other words, `Vue.prototype` is not reactive. This, most likely, answers your question.
  To get past the problem, I placed a reactive object on `Vue.prototype`, which can be updated without being replaced: `$state`.

---

<sup>***1***</sup> - there might be an exception to this rule:  when you place text nodes inside a `<template>`, a `<div>` wrapper might be created to hold the text node(s). This behaviour might not be consistent across Vue versions.
<sup>***2***</sup> - `Vue.Observable()` was added in `2.6.0`. It's a stand-alone export of Vue's reactivity module (like a component's `data()`, but without the component). In v3.x `Vue.Observable()` was renamed `Vue.reactive()`, to avoid confusion/conflation with `rxjs`'s Observable.

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed explanation. the problem is my component is in different file and the change made to the variable (state.foo) , it is in different file.

Comment: That should not matter. Use [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). I bet you're already using them.

Comment: Consider [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your local project into codesandbox and explain in clear what you're trying to do and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`global variables` are accessed in template without `this` keyword which means `$val===1` will work.

**Solution 1**:

```html
<template>
 <component1 v-if='$val === 1' />
 <component2 v-else/>
</template>
```

This will work.

But you could make use of [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) in your case.

**Solution 2**:

```html
<template>
    <component :is='currentComponent'/>
</template>

<script>
\\imports of your components will go here
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    component1, component2
  },
  computed:{
    currentComponent(){
      return this.$val === 1?component1:component2;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`Dynamic components` are more performant and helps you maintain state of component.

Comment: Property or method "val" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

When I changed this.val to val I am getting this error

Comment: How have you declared `$val` globally could you add that code in question?

Comment: added the code for global val

Comment: Have you declared $val in main.js were vue is instantiated. could you provide entire code of your component and js files?

Comment: yes i have instantiated it well. The value is also getting updated but vue is not recomputing or re-rendering that component